# Any suggestions for repairs of nasty cracks in my walls and the door?

Tags: drywall, doors, patching-drywall

I have 1 day to finish all those repairs before a new person moves in. Is there any way I could fix them fast and reliably? The first one is a hole in a dry wall and the last one is a door which is not that solid (a kick or two and you have such cracks). I was considering using a mash tape and white paint for the wall holes, but not sure how good that idea is given that I have no experience. As for the door, I am really lost.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the wall you need to cut out the entire square of drywall out, mud and tape it, sand it, paint it.  With fast drying mud and a fan you can do this in 6 hours easy and maybe 30-45 mins of actual work.

For a door the only thing you can do is try to Bondo it but it should be replaced.  If you are leaving the place they might charge you for the door even if you fix it.  If you are renting it out the Bondo should be OK.

Comment: 15 minute hot mud can cut it down to less than an hour for the sheetrock. Just dont use more than you need because it is very hard to sand.

Comment: +1 for the 15 minute mud (also called Dura-Bond). Don't mix more than you can use in 10 minutes. I have repaired doors by removing  the door knob, glue and screw a piece of 3/16 lauan plywood to the door face. Prime and paint, then reinstall the knob.

Answer (score 0):

On the sheet rock cut out a square and install new sheet rock.  Tape,spackel,and paint.  You can mix plaster with your joint compound and it will set up faster.  The door is junk it should be replaced.  If not choose a wood puddy and sand smooth or replace the skin on the door.